# SPDataSource filtering error

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Does anyone have an idea why the following code doesn't work?

```
    SPDataSource source = new SPDataSource();
    source.List = list;
    source.SelectCommand = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Person' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + currentUser.ID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    gridView.DataSource = source;
    gridView.DataBind(); // <- Breaks here
```

Basically I am trying to filter the list for the current user and only display the items that have his name in the "Person" field.
Also, it works without the SelectCommand, so I assume my query is wrong, but do not understand why it fails. I tried declaring value type as user and assigning it currentUser.Name, but it also failed.

Comment: can you post the actual error?

Comment: It is not in English :( But I'll try translating - "One or more fields are not declared correctly. Navigate to the page of list parameters and delete those fields"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that either your field name or datatype is invalid.

Comment: Apparently, it can not query fields with names in Cyrillic

Comment: Also, I didn't know it had to be an internal name of the field, so now it works.